# How to do double-sided reveal in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation

I have a RelativeLayout containing information that I want to be positioned statically on screen (no perceptible movement). But I need to animate it "opening" from about 1/3 of the way from the left.

eg, let's say it contains the text "A quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog"

It should animate something like:

```
            n
           wn fo
          own fox j
            ...
  quick brown fox jumped over the lazy
  quick brown fox jumped over the lazy d
A quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog
```

How do I accomplish this?

I can't have two blocks obscuring the content that move out of the way, because I need to be able to see the content behind the layout until it's obscured by the animation. (Unless you know how to make an "invisibility block" that makes the portion of its parent that it covers invisible. :P)

I tried having a clipping linear layout container that animated to the left and wider while the content was translated to the right, but this results in noticeable jitter with slow animations and goes out of sync by a number of pixels at shorter durations.

My guess is I'm going to have to override onDraw, but I'm not clear on how to do so.

Answer (score 0):

No need to override `onDraw`. You can use [Fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) and/or [animations](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidAnimation/article.html).

Comment: You're going to have to elaborate on that. As I said, I already tried animations and the closest I got is a jitter. And I really don't see what fragments can do to help.

Comment: Sorry, I was as **very** grim mood when I wrote that and my head was simply elsewhere. I had similar problems once, and my final solution was, I'm afraid, a hack: I snapped a picture of the screen, put it into a hovering fragment, animated that, then quickly flashed back the interface into place. The effect worked, though it was obviously less than optimal as an implementation. Seems animating live controls can be taxing, but a simple picture is not

Comment: Can you describe how you animated that? I can't get the sliding to work without animating the containing view left, which requires counter-animating the content to the right, which leaves me with dueling animations that don't combine perfectly.

Comment: Replace the view that's siding out with a picture, move the real view underneath with no animation, then vanish the picture. Sorry I can't be code-specific, I've long switched to HTML/JS/CSS for apps